# elements (image) between <li> in horizontal <ul>

Tags: image, html-lists, separator

I need to place image separator between [ li ] tags.After one hour googling I find two
common ways to add separator:

- make right(left) [ li ] border visible  (not in my case)
- set background for [ li ]:   url(../images/separator.png) no-repeat left;

Second approach not satisfyed me as my image geometry and [ li ] geometry are different.
So,how can I achive this goals? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing additional [li]-elements between the others.

```
<li class="seperator">
```

Now you can edit the css to make them fitting your background img.